# How can I use multiple or selectors in fancybox 3?

Tags: fancybox-3

Can someone help me in adding multiple selectors if possible in

```
$().fancybox({
    selector : '.imglist a:visible'
});
```

eg

```
$().fancybox({
    selector : '.imglist a:visible, .owl-item'
});
```

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Your last snippet works perfectly fine, it is a valid selector - https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

If you have any issue, then, please, create a live demo so it would be possible to investigate your problem and to give a helpful answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is working properly as you suggested.  It seems the problem I have is the grouping is not working for some reason.  If I have one gallery on a page it works fine, however if I have multiple galleries the data-fancybox="gallery" is ignored and all photos are grouped together regardless of the value in the data-fancybox.

Comment: Sorry, but this is how it works - using `selector` creates one big gallery from all elements that matches the selector.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it properly as this is the what I am trying to achieve https://codepen.io/mellowtothemax/pen/VqeNEP. Here using selector and different data-fancybox values does group them properly.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, the selector comma is not an or logical operator.  Is there a way to achieve what I am after?

Comment: For a demo using OwlCarousel2, see answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759044/fancybox-with-owl-carousel-lazyload

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted.  I managed to use ('[data-fancybox^="gallery"]') for multiple galleries on same page and use selector only for specific galleries like isotope.  Unfortunately I use owlcarousel1 and the cloned class only exists in owlcarousel2.